# WPF coded UI test doesn't trigger the change of bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, coded-ui-tests

I have a WPF view and create a radio button on it programmatically:

```
// public class MyView
var radioButton = new RadioButton
{
    Name = "NameGoesHere",
    Content = "Use alternative option",
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    IsChecked = false
};
radioButton.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("UseAlternativeOption")
{
    Converter = new CustomNullableBoolConverter(),
    ConverterParameter = true,
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
});
panel.Children.Add(radioButton);
```

This radio button has a two-way binding to a property in my view model:

```
// public class MyViewModel
public bool? UseAlternativeOption
{
    get
    {
        return _useAlternativeOption;
    }
    set
    { // breakpoint here is not being hit when updated from automated UI test scenario
        _useAlternativeOption = value ?? false;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UseAlternativeOption));
    }
}
```

Now, when I click this radio button in the application, it correctly calls a property setter and sets the value.

The problem is that it doesn't work when I try to do the same from coded UI test:

```
// public class MyUnitTests
var alternativeOptionRadioButton = UIControlBuilder<WpfRadioButton>.Builder()
    .Parent(ContentPane)
    .AutomationID(AlternativeOptionRadioButtonAutomationID)
    .Build();

alternativeOptionRadioButton.Selected = true;
Assert.AreEqual(true, viewModel.UseAlternativeOption);
```

I see that the radio button is selected on the form and can see that `Selected` property is `true`, but the viewmodel setter is not being hit. I have put a breakpoint on `_useAlternativeOption = value ?? false` line and it doesn't get hit, while it is hit when run outside of UI test scenario and clicked manually.

Is there anything I am missing?
How to make RadioButton trigger the change of its `Binding` within automated UI test scenario?

Comment: By the way, `OnClick` event is getting triggered both in user-interactive and automated UI test scenarios, so the radio button is clicked for sure.

Comment: Are you sure the debugger is attached to the correct process? The process running the coded UI test is likely a different process from the actual application process. If you just try to debug the coded UI test, you won’t hit any breakpoints in the actual application unless you also attach to that process.

Comment: @DaveM It makes so much sense. Actually, the model is updating correctly, but I just didn't realize that I am actually debugging UI tests, not application under test. Thanks. You could post it as an answer, so that it can help other developers who stumble upon this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coded UI Tests run in a different process from the application under test. So, make sure your debugger is actually attached to the correct process. You won't hit any breakpoints in the application code unless you also attach the debugger to that process.

To do this in Visual Studio 2017, go to `Debug` > `Attach To Process...` and select the process of the application under test.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the true/false value, try performing a SendKeys with a {SPACE} key. If space doesn't work, try {ENTER}. I hope this gets you through.

```
if(!alternativeOptionRadioButton.Selected)
{
    Keyboard.SendKeys(alternativeOptionRadioButton, "{SPACE}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, the problem was that I did actually confuse the fact that I didn't actually debug my application and coded UI test are running in a different process.